# Circular Motion and Elasticity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

> A mass $0.3\,\text{kg}$ is whirled around in a circle by a light elastic cord of unstretched length $0.6\,\text{m}$ and elastic modulus $\lambda=30\,\text{N}$. If each revolution takes $1.5$ seconds find:
>
> (a) the tension in the cable;
> (b) the angle $\theta$ made by the cord with the vertical.
>
> [image]

**My Doubts:**
Elastic modulus should be in $\text{N}/\text{m}^2$ but here it is in Newtons only. Is this correct or they just mean here $k=30\,\text{N}/\text{m}$ ? What do you want to say about $\lambda = 30\,\text{N}$ ?

Do you think my equations are correct to solve for correct answer

**My Try:**

Let $x$ be the elongation, so we have
$$T\cos\theta=mg$$
$$T\sin\theta=m\omega^2 r \;\;\;,\;\;\;r=(l+x)\sin\theta$$
$$T=kx$$

Using these three equations I can solve for $\theta\;\;,\;\; T$. is this correct?

Comment: I agree that this is likely a typo and that 30 N/m is probably the intended meaning.

Comment: Yes, your formulation is correct.

Comment: no it is not .., i already corrected that.

Comment: i understood finally lambda :) it is T/\epsilon

Comment: Probably the question came from Applied Mathematics where the elastic modulus (different from both Young's Modulus and spring constant) is measured in Newtons. It is related to spring constant by $k=\lambda/L$ where $L$ is the natural length of the spring. https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/mechanics/elastic-strings